# EdgeOptions or Capabilities are not avaliable to disable Edge Sidebar on version v111.0.1661.51

Tags: testing, automation

Hi I can see Edge sidebar is getting visible even after this solution :

```
DESIRED_CAPABILITIES = {    
  edge:    { 
edge: { 
             browser_opts: { args:    %w( --disable-features=msHubApps),
   
}
    browser_opts: {args:    %w( --disable-features=msHubApps),}
}
}
}
```

}

On Edge version v111.0.1661.51 Edge Sidebar is visible why?

Do you have any idea on it??